# Installing and Importing scapy

Tags: scapy

I have installed scapy onto my macbook pro but I cannot import it into vscode. Also when I try to run it from the terminal, it says "command not found." I have spent hours trying to figure this out. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

from scapy.all import sniff
do this